# When I include brackets in a nested for loop, it doesn't function correctly but when I take them out it does; why is this?

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

When I write this program to print out prime numbers, it works correctly without the brackets in the nested for loop:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int p, d;
    _Bool isPrime;

    for (p = 2; p <= 50; ++p)
    {
        isPrime = 1;

        for (d = 2; d < p; ++d)
        if ( p % d == 0)
            isPrime = 0;

        if (isPrime != 0)
            printf("%i ", p);
}

printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

But when I do the following:

```
for (p = 2; p <= 50; ++p)
{
    isPrime = 1;

    for (d = 2; d < p; ++d)
    {
        if ( p % d == 0)
            isPrime = 0;

        if (isPrime != 0)
            printf("%i ", p);
    }
}

printf("\n");
return 0;
```

It prints the the prime number multiple times (the same amount of times as the value of the previous prime number). Also it prints out 9 as well.

Anyone any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Because the brackets will include the printing statement in the iteration and so the number will be printed while being checked. `9 % 2 == 0` is false and `9 % 3 == 0` is true, so `9` is printed once.

Comment: Thanks MikeCAT. When the loop iterates, doesn't it include those statements anyway as they are both indented after the loop begins?

Comment: @rayzor No. C is free-format language, so indentations will mean nothing for compilers.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So when I put brackets around the outer loop, that iterates through everything within them even if that includes another loop? Unless that nested loop has brackets?

Comment: The effect of `for` is one statement after `for(...)`. Using `{}`, you can make one statement (compound statement) from multiple statements.

Comment: This now makes perfect sense. My confusion began at thinking the indentation played a role. Thanks.

Comment: @rayzor: indentation does play a part in some languages, such as Python - not so in C. I tend towards the view that one should _always_ use braces for blocks in C, even for one-liners; not doing so can be a source of bugs.